# How to classify japanese characters as either kanji or Katakana or Hiragana?

Tags: sorting, unicode, sqlite, cjk, icu

I am working on some application which require sorting of Japans languages.

Sorting of Japanese needs to have Katakana and Kanji converted to Hiragana and then sorted according to the UTF-8 code.

The Hiragana, Katakana, and Kanji characters shall be combined together and sorted by the Hiragana equivalent “spelling.” Note: using the Hiragana “alphabet” – a, i, u, e, o, ka, ki, ku, ke, ki, etc.

Now to do this task, I need :

1.Classify japanese characters as either kanji or Katakana or Hiragana.

2.Convert  Katakana and Kanji  to Hiragana .

3.Apply algorithm which carry out sorting base on phonetic sound(Hiragana).

The Database of application is in UTF-8 .

Now to carry out 1st step:
"Classify japanese characters as either kanji or Katakana or Hiragana." ,

I want to know if there is any APIs present for C or C++ programing language in Sqlite3 , QT , ICU or any other package  which can give Unicode of Character ?

On the Base of Unicode, we can easily classify Japanese characters.

Please correct me if I am wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As you say, Japanese characters can easily be sorted into group using Unicode. This is trivial.
2. Conversion of katakana to hiragana is also trivial as there is a one to one mapping. You can convert kanji to hiragana via [Kakasi](http://kakasi.namazu.org/)
3. Sorting can be done by converting to hiragana first. However, this is a poor man's sort as many kanji are homophones (same sound, different kanji). So you should sort the Kanji before converting and sorting by hiragana.

You don't say why you need to do sorting in this way. Maybe there is a better sort we can suggest if you tell us more about your application.

Comment: Hi Koan, Application requirement  say : Japanese character lists shall be sorted by Hiragana/Katakana/Kanji  Special Characters  Alphabet  Digits.   The Hiragana, Katakana, and Kanji characters shall be combined together and sorted by the Hiragana equivalent “spelling.” Note: using the Hiragana “alphabet” – a, i, u, e, o, ka, ki, ku, ke, ki, etc.
In the case where the exact same sounds exist for Hiragana, Katakana, and Kanji, then the sorted order shall be Hiragana  Katakana  Kanji.      Can you please more better way to sort Japanese language  ?

Comment: Application requirement also say : Sorting of Japanese needs to have Katagana and Kanja converted to Hiragana and then sorted according to the UTF-8 code.     For sorting tables name dictionaries shall be used. Here are some links to OpenSource dictionary:

http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENAMDICT

Comment: I don't know the "correct" way to sort Japanese, it depends on your application and you only told me the requirements. You didn't say if you are trying to implement dictionary order, or not. I am using EDICT already, it is very good.

Comment: Koan, Can you please give your inputs & share experience like logical steps to carry out this task . It will be great help to learn from you.  Thanks

Comment: I use EDICT. It has the reading for kanji included so there is no reason to generate kana. For classification, I look up words by kana or by kanji; but I don't try to make a mixed dictionary of both. It looks to me that you want to do a proper dictionary sort, I would forget about what your application requirement says and implement a proper dictionary sort. I don't know that there is a standard kanji order, you could use something like http://www.simon-cozens.org/content/sorting-japanese-dictionary-order

Comment: Koan, If Kana is different than Katagana & Hiragana ? may be i need to first understand basic of Japanese Language before going to sort this task .... :-)  Can you please suggest me some good link to understand Japanese language . Also please suggest links which  help me to carry out this sorting task ...

Comment: Kana is the collective word for Hiragana and Katakana. As I said, I don't know that there is a single best/correct method for sorting Kanji; I think you're going to have to learn some more about Japanese language and Google sorting methods.